# How to add a Column to stored procedure result?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have the following sql procedure:

```
DECLARE @temp table
    (
       Column1 nvarchar(1000)
    )

    INSERT @temp (Column1)
    SELECT  fld_4
    FROM    MyTable
    WHERE   fld_1 = @param1 and
            fld_2 = @param2 and
            fld_3 = @param3

     SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Column1 ASC) AS Number, Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Result
     FROM  
     (
         SELECT Column1,  
             CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(Column1, ';', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Result  
         FROM  @temp
     ) AS A CROSS APPLY Result.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a);
```

Structure of MyTable:

```
| fld_1 | fld_2 | fld_3 | fld_4 | ... | fld_9 | ...|
```

Where fld_4 contains something like this:

```
-9;-9;-1;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-1;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-1;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-1;-9;-1;-9;-9;-9;-1;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-1;-1;-1;-1;-9;-1;-1;-9;-9;-9;-9;-1;-9;-1;-9;-9;-9;-1;-9;-1;-9;-1;-9;-9;-9;-9;-1;-9;-9;-1;-1;-9;-1;-1;0000;FFF8;-9;-9;-9;-1;-9;-1;-9;FFF6;-9;-1;-9;-1;-9;-1;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9;-9
```

My procedure returns a table with this structure:

```
| Number | Result |
|   1    |   -9   |
|   2    |   -9   |
|   3    |   -1   |
|  ...   |   ...  |
```

Now, I want to achieve the following result:

```
| Number | Result |     NewColumn    |
|   1    |   -9   |  Value of fld_9  |
|   2    |   -9   |  Value of fld_9  |
|   3    |   -1   |  Value of fld_9  |
|  ...   |   ...  |  Value of fld_9  |
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call a `Stored Procedure` result directly..

However you can make `view` or  or [table-valued user-defined](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/intro-to-user-defined-functions-updated) function then get results..

Other way insert Stored Procedure result on `TempTable`

```
INSERT INTO #tempTable EXEC MyStoredProcedure
```

look at this **Quick Sample**

```
Create PROCEDURE SampleStoreProc    
AS
BEGIN   
    Select 'Burak', 1 
END
GO


Create Table #TempTable
(    
    MyCol Varchar(50),
    ReferanceCol int
)

Insert into #TempTable Exec SampleStoreProc 

go

Create Table TestTable2 
(
    MyCol2 varchar(250),
    RefCol int
);

go

Insert into TestTable2 values ('Yeni', 1);

Select a.MyCol, b.MyCol2 From #TempTable a
left join TestTable2 b on b.RefCol = a.ReferanceCol
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking, you simply want another column included in your result set. Something like the following snippet should work. Keep your `FROM`clause, and add `, MyTable` to the end of it.

```
...
SELECT 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Column1 ASC) AS Number
    , Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Result
    , fld_9 AS NewColumn
FROM 
...
    , MyTable
WHERE
    MyTable.fld_1 = @param1 AND
    MyTable.fld_2 = @param2 AND
    MyTable.fld_3 = @param3;
```